# pandas outer join on multiple keys

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

merged_df = pd.merge(left = df1, right = df2, on = ["id", "date"], how = "outer")

Hypothetical data -

df1  -

| id | date | value1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2021-01-01 | 200 |
| 101 | 2021-01-03 | 400 |

df2  -

| id | date | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2021-01-01 | 600 |
| 101 | 2021-01-02 | 900 |

My expected result is -

| id | date | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2021-01-01 | 200 | 600 |
| 101 | 2021-01-02 | NaN | 900 |
| 101 | 2021-01-03 | 400 | NaN |

Current results -

| id | date | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2021-01-01 | 200 | 600 |
| 101 | 2021-01-03 | 400 | NaN |

I am unable to figure out where it is going wrong.

Edit 01: It looks like it is missing the df2 rows when it doesn't exist in df1.

Changing the how to left and right works as expected but when it comes to outer it is not working as expected.

Comment: What is `print (df1.dtypes)` and `print (df2.dtypes)` ? Are same dtypes for `["id", "date"]` ?

Comment: I changed the dtype of id in df1 to int as well and performed the join, still the results arent correct.

Comment: Can you add your incorretr result to question?

Comment: Would that be the date columns in the 2 dataframe with different dtypes e.g. one in string (object) and one in datetime64  ?  Please print the dtypes as jezrael suggested.

Comment: @SeaBean both date columns have datetime64[ns] as dtype.

Comment: Your data workign perfectly for me. It seems there is `how = "left"` instead `how = "outer"` for wrong ouput